# Why is a 1 character .NET string 32 bytes in x64?

Tags: .net, string, memory, .net-4.0

I've been trying to figure out the overhead of a string in .NET 4 x64. This is what I've got so far.

- 16 byte object header for x64
- 4 bytes for the stringLength field (arrayLength is gone in .NET 4)
- (length + 1) * 2 bytes for the string content (UTF-16, null terminated)

So you'd expect a 1 character string to be 16 + 4 + 4 = **24 bytes**. It's divisible by 8 so it shouldn't need any padding.

But when I look at the sizes in WinDbg I see them taking **32 bytes**. When I `!dumpobject` them they say their size is 28 bytes, which is what I assume is getting rounded up to 32. What's going on? Is there another round of memory alignment happening?

Comment: Try making the string longer... How much memory for 2, 3 and 4 characters?

Comment: @xanatos: 2 bytes extra per character.

Comment: The start character maybe aligned?

Comment: @leppie So 28 = 1 char, 30 = 2 char, 32 = 3 char and 34 = 4 char?

Comment: @xanatos: Read the question again. 1 char is 32 :)

Comment: A 3 character string is also 32 bytes (Size of 32 with `!dumpobject`). A 4 character string is 40 bytes (Size of 34 with `!dumpobject`).

Comment: @RandomEngy !dumpobject is 28 for 1, 32 for 3 and ?? for 2?

Comment: @xanatos I didn't check explicitly but I am guessing it would be 30.

Comment: Confirmed.  It is always padded with an extra 4 bytes of zero.  Hard to explain, doesn't happen in 32-bit mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I *suspect* that the first character is aligned on an 8-byte boundary on x64, so that when passed as a pointer to unmanaged code, it's a properly-aligned pointer. Your figures certainly fit in with [the ones I got measuring string size](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/04/05/of-memory-and-strings.aspx) recently, leading to formulae of:

```
32 bit: 14 + length * 2 (rounded up to 4 bytes) 
64 bit: 26 + length * 2 (rounded up to 8 bytes)
```

So in a 64 bit CLR, even a 0-length string takes 32 bytes by my reckoning.

Comment: It does seem likely it's 8-byte alignment on the first character plus 8-byte padding on the object as a whole. I suppose a follow-up question would be what fields get aligned like this. I poked around and it doesn't seem to be a general rule: for example when you mix longs and ints in a class they're happy to pack tightly together and not align on 8-byte boundaries. Internet searches turned up nothing. :(

Comment: Strings are copied using native-size ints, so I suppose they are aligned in part at least so they can be copied more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Rounding up to paragraph (16-byte) boundaries to optimize cache line fills on Intel processors?

Comment: I don't think this is it because I'm seeing a bunch of 40 byte strings in WinDbg as well.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you can't rely on anything on the implementation side with .NET - just because it is x bytes on your machine, doesn't mean it is x bytes on some other machine/.NET version. i.e. it is dangerous to do anything in code with knowledge of the internal struct layout of .NET classes.

Comment: True, but this particular question appears to be out of simple curiousity.